# Is there a way to disable Search Engine in IE 11 that can work in SharePoint Online?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, search-results, internet-explorer

I have been finding for a solution on this issue. 
And as I have been trying to build up an e-examination system on my SharePoint Online system. I am thinking that if there's a possible way to disable search engine, so that user will not be able to, i.e. google or wiki the answer. Or having to have a new tab/window feature on the Internet Explorer.

I hope that there's some solution. :)